# Convert multibyte hex back to UTF-8 string

Tags: string, delphi, utf-8

In Delphi 10.4, I have a hexadecimal representation of a string:

```
function TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, nr : integer;
  Input, HexStr, h: String;
begin
  HexStr := '';
  Input := Edit2.Text;
  for i:=1 to Length(Input) do begin
    nr := Ord(Input[i]);
    h := IntToHex(nr, 0);
    if Length(h) = 1 then
      h := '0' + h;
    HexStr := HexStr + h;
  end;
  Edit3.Text := HexStr;
end;
```

For "**abc€**", I get "61626320AC" here. Note the € sign converts to "20AC".
Now for converting it back to a normal string, I split that hex into 2-char pairs, using `StrToInt()` with a '$' prefix. I have no indicator for it being 4 chars long for an € sign, instead of 2 chars, and this breaks the euro sign:

[image]

How do I convert back such a hex string without breaking multibyte characters?

Comment: Internally Delphi uses `WideChar` and `UnicodeString`. Thus you should use `IntToHex(nr, 4)` to get four digit representation of each character. Thus your `Edit3.Text` should be `00610062006320AC`. Then to convert back to normal text you would always convert 4-digit codes to characters.

Comment: @TomBrunberg "*Internally Delphi uses `WideChar` and `WideString`*" - `string` is an alias for `UnicodeString`, not `WideString`. Although they are both UTF-16, there are big functional differences between them.

Comment: @Anse your question's title mentions UTF-8, but nothing in your code touches UTF-8, so you should fix the title.

Comment: Your encoding is wrong, it should be 616263E282AC. Decode it by converting hex to byte array and then pass through TEncoding.UTF8.GetString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no indicator for it being 4 chars long for an € sign, instead of 2 chars

And because of that reason alone, you simply won't be able to convert `"61626320AC"` back to `"abc€"`, because you don't know which hex codes are 2 digits and which are 4 digits, you didn't deliminate them. For instance, the hex codes `6162` and `6263` also represent valid Unicode characters, too.

As @TomBrunberg mentioned in comments, you can use 4-digit hex codes for every character, eg:

```pascal
function TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, nr : integer;
  Input, HexStr, h: String;
begin
  HexStr := '';
  Input := Edit2.Text;
  for i := Low(Input) to High(Input) do begin
    nr := Ord(Input[i]);
    h := IntToHex(nr, 4);
    HexStr := HexStr + h;
  end;
  Edit3.Text := HexStr;
end;
```

Then you can convert back by splitting up the hex string into 4-character groups when calling `StrToInt()`, eg:

```pascal
function TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, nr : integer;
  Output, HexStr, h: String;
begin
  HexStr := Edit3.Text;
  Output := '';
  i := Low(HexStr);
  while i <= High(HexStr) do begin
    h := Copy(HexStr, i, 4);
    nr := StrToInt('$' + h);
    Output := Output + Char(nr);
    Inc(i, 4);
  end;
  Edit2.Text := Output;
end;
```

Or, as @AmigoJack hinted at, you can use UTF-8 instead, eg:

```pascal
function TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, nr : integer;
  HexStr, h: String;
  Input: UTF8String;
begin
  HexStr := '';
  Input := UTF8String(Edit2.Text);
  for i := Low(Input) to High(Input) do begin
    nr := Ord(Input[i]);
    h := IntToHex(nr, 2);
    HexStr := HexStr + h;
  end;
  Edit3.Text := HexStr;
end;

function TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, nr : integer;
  HexStr, h: String;
  Output: UTF8String;
begin
  HexStr := Edit3.Text;
  Output := '';
  i := Low(HexStr);
  while i <= High(HexStr) do begin
    h := Copy(HexStr, i, 2);
    nr := StrToInt('$' + h);
    Output := Output + AnsiChar(nr);
    Inc(i, 2);
  end;
  Edit2.Text := string(Output);
end;
```

Comment: I think OP assumes a `String` is UTF-8 (hence the tag; this is also the case in Lazarus) - then decoding a hex string can be done by the same self-syncing rules as of UTF-8. This answer is correct for Delphi and its UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: @AmigoJack Delphi does not use UTF-8 for `String`, and never has (though one can argue that `AnsiString` can hold a UTF-8 string, with proper care). FPC/Lazarus still uses `AnsiString` for `string` by default, unless `{$modeswitch UnicodeStrings}` is used (ie, as in `${mode DelphiUnicode}`). As for UTF-8 itself, `€` would not be `$20AC` in UTF-8, it would be `$E2 $82 $AC` instead. If the OP were actually creating a UTF-8 encoded hex string, that would actually be quite easy to decode back into a normal string. But they are not, which makes the conversion back much more difficult.